# React.js Simple component composition issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to reproduce the following simple HTML code in react:

**Classic HTML**

```
<div>
  Hello
  <div>child</div>
  <div>child</div>
  <div>child</div>
</div>
```

**React(works)**

```
var HelloComponent = React.createClass(
{
  render: function()
  {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello
        <div>child</div>
        <div>child</div>
        <div>child</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var mount = React.render(<HelloComponent/>, document.body);
```

**React(not works)**

```
var childComponent = React.createClass(
{
  render: function()
  {
    return (<div>child</div>);
  }
});

var HelloComponent = React.createClass(
{
  render: function()
  {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello
        <childComponent/>
        <childComponent/>
        <childComponent/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var mount = React.render(<HelloComponent/>, document.body);
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
createSourceCodeErrorMessage
transformCode
...
```

What do I miss?? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Captilize the component name. From the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components):

> **HTML Tags vs. React Components**
>
> React can either render HTML tags (strings) or React components
>   (classes).
>
> To render a HTML tag, just use lower-case tag names in JSX:
>
> ```
> var myDivElement = <div className="foo" />;
> React.render(myDivElement, document.body);
> ```
>
> To render a React Component, just create a local variable that starts
>   with an upper-case letter:
>
> ```
> var MyComponent = React.createClass({/*...*/});
> var myElement = <MyComponent someProperty={true} />;
> React.render(myElement, document.body);
> ```
>
> React's JSX uses the upper vs. lower case convention to distinguish
>   between local component classes and HTML tags.